# New page with primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

a newbie primefaces question:

When I create a simple primeface page, what should I put in order to have the text styled?

```
<h:body>
    <!-- Ok, what I put here to have styled the following H1 and outputText? -->
    <h1>Not styled h1</h1>
    <h:outputText value="Not styled text." />
</h:body>
</html>
```

I am able to get styled text by placing it inside a <\p:panel>, but I find that a bit annoying to place everything in panels.

Comment: What do you mean by *styled text*? I guess you want to apply a theme to your page. Follow the steps [here](http://primefaces.org/themes.html).

Comment: I have the theme loaded and working (boostrap). What I mean is what I have to include on a new jsf2 page to have all elements beeing styled? (something in the h:head?)

Comment: I guess the theme applies for PrimeFaces visible components only (those with `<p:something>`), not for every component in your page.

Comment: Why don't you put the whole content in `h:body` into one `p:panel`? I mean: `<h:body><p:panel>...</p:panel></h:body>`

Comment: I don't find that really elegant. This is why I am asking :)
`<p:panel style="border: none;">...</p:panel>` is what I was starting to use. (Ok, it produce only a <div> but why I have to place all my contents inside this div?)

I found that `<h:body styleClass="ui-widget">` can do the trick too. (But is it the right way to do?)

Answer (score 0):

Use css to change it, it's the most elegant solution. You can create your own classes or override existing primefaces ones if you're sure you aren't going to use the original ones. Remember to add `!important` at the end of the attributes set.

```
.ui-panel
{
   border: black solid 1px !important;
}
```

You can just follow [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-override-primefaces-css/) about how and where to add your css reference in order to make Primefaces styles overriden.